# How to format formatted string using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have `2017-12-21 07:53:21` -> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM-SS formatted string. I want to convert it to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss = `21/12/2017 07:53:21`

I am using momentjs to convert but it returns `21/53/2017 07:53:21`

Here is my code sample :

```
return moment(row.creationDate).format('DD/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
```

Comment: `return moment(row.creationDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');`

Comment: @JoshKisb what an easy mistake, i am sorry. Thank you and please dont vote down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capitalization of the format string matters. From the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

`m` is minute

`M` is month

Here is a corrected format string:

```
return moment(row.creationDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
```